# How to inject javascript code in firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, web, firefox

In chrome I use custom [javascript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) to copy paste a certain script I need to test in multiple browsers. In this case it;s simple and easy just click on the extension and the editor opens.

I need to do the same in firefox. I have tried [this extension](https://mybrowseraddon.com/custom-style-script.html), but the documentation for it is very unclear. I am not sure how to open the editor to paste the java script code into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GreaseMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) Add On for running user-scripts with Firefox. Very popular and works well.

Comment: So, either my script is not working on firefox or I don't know how to use Greasemonkey. I click on the monkey, then on the pop up I click on 'New user script', paste the script and save then refresh teh page. But I see no change in the page itself.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used it. Perhaps some sort of trigger must initiate the script? Try wrapping it in a `window.onload = function(){...}` and see if it works.